# One query that matches values with only one condition out of two, one query that matches values with both conditions

Tags: sql, filter, amazon-redshift

I'm having some sort of a blank about how to do this in SQL.

Consider this reprex in R

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame(ID = (sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T)),
       status = (sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = T)),
       amount = (sample(seq(1,50,0.01),10)))
```

which gives out this table

```
   ID status amount
1   3     no  29.87
2   3    yes  26.66
3   2    yes  15.49
4   2    yes  18.89
5   3    yes  44.06
6   5     no  30.79
7   4    yes  17.13
8   1    yes   6.54
9   2    yes  45.68
10  3    yes  12.66
```

I need to find two SQL queries.

One where I select the ID's that only have status of 'NO'
meaning ID 5.

and

One where I select the ID's that match both conditions, meaning ID 3

I have a query for both but I'm almost sure it's not correct so any lead is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the query you have, and why it's not producing the results you want.

Comment: I'm basically using a biger dataset so I'm creating two temporary tables.

`create temp table no_only as  
select ID   
from table   
where status = 'no'  
and status != 'yes';    
--  
create temp table yes_only as   
select ID  
from table  
where status != 'no'  
and status = 'yes';      
--  
select ID   
from table  
where id not in (select ID from only_yes)
and id not in (select ID from only_no); `

Comment: The first query is always going to return wrong results. The status on a single row is either no or yes, and you explicitly ask for status = no and status is not yes (also no). You will want to do a self-join. I.e. something like 'SELECT ID FROM table AS a LEFT JOIN table AS b ON a.id = b.id AND a.status <> b.status WHERE a.Status = 'No' AND b.status IS NULL`. I cannot test it at this moment, but try and run that and see whether it meets oyur needs. For the second query, change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, and remove the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One where I select the ID's that only have status of 'NO' meaning ID 5.

```
select id from your_table where status='no' and id not in (select id from 
your_table  where status='yes')
```

> One where I select the ID's that match both conditions, meaning ID 3

```
select id from your_table where status='no' and id  in (select id from 
your_table where status='yes')
```

At last I think you are expecting ids which do not match these conditions. so `UNION` both queries and get ids of your table which not exists after `UNION`

```
select id from your_table where id not in (
    select id from your_table where status='no' and id not in 
    (select id from your_table where status='yes')
    union all
    select id from your_table where status='no' and id  in 
    (select id from your_table where status='yes')
)
```